# LEFT JOIN. Column 'product_id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT product_id,time_id,customer_id,promotion_id,store_id,store_sales,store_cost,SUM(unit_sales) total_unit_sales

FROM sales_fact_1997 a
LEFT JOIN product p ON (a.product_id = p.product_id)

group by product_id order by total_unit_sales;
```

I am wondering why I am getting an error:

Column 'product_id' in field list is ambiguous

Both of the tables I am referencing have a column for product_id.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql doesn't know which product_id you want.  You need to use the alias before the "product_id" column in the select.  i.e. (assume you want the product_id form sales_fact_1997),

```
SELECT a.product_id,time_id,customer_id,promotion_id,store_id,store_sales,store_cost,SUM(unit_sales) total_unit_sales

FROM sales_fact_1997 a
LEFT JOIN product p ON (a.product_id = p.product_id)

group by a.product_id order by total_unit_sales;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have actually answered your own question:

> Both of the tables I am referencing have a column for product_id.

Therefore you need to qualify *which* one you want (in the `SELECT` column list). Do you want `a.product_id` or the (possibly-null-because-of-the-left-join) `p.product_id`?

*Note: Yes, you still have to qualify which one you want to select even if a join, where, or constraint would ensure all versions of said column name have the same value.*